# On Click event on <td> created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have the following table which is created dynamically using a onload function at the beginning.

```
<div id="first">
<table class="joma" id="joma">
<tbody>
<tr>
   <th>Id</th>
   <th>V No</th>
   <th>Biboron</th>
   <th>Taka</th>
</tr>
<tr><td class="rid">1</td><td>sss</td><td>222</td><td class="cv">4</td></tr>
<tr><td class="rid">2</td><td>xxx</td><td>2333</td><td class="cv">4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Now I need to be able to click the `<td class="rid">` which should give the the corresponding value. in this case 1 or 2.

How do I do this?

I have used the following methods:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rid').click(function() {
        alert(this);
    });
});



$('.rid').click(function() {
    alert(this);
});
```

I am not getting anything with this.

Comment: getting [object Object]

Comment: alert($(this).text()); or alert($(this).html()); $(this) object means its td. if you write console.log($(this)); you can view it in chrome and firefox console by right clicking on page and select Inspect element.

Comment: So, your click handler is fired or not??? What is your issue? You seem to say than alert() works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click','.rid',function() {
     alert("this");
});
```

when page loaded DOM is created `.rid` is not the part of the page.

So you can not access them directly you have to use `event delegation`

Comment: You can also use $(document).ready({ $('.rid').live('click',function() { });  }); its the same as .on().

Answer (score 3):

Use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.rid', function() {
    alert("this");
});
```

`.rid` doesn't exist on page load, so bind it to an element that does exist (usually the container to where your appending the content, but since I didn't see one, `document` is a safe bet).

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the `<tbody>` as the container?

Comment: @user2736012 -- OP said the table was loaded dynamically, so `tbody` would be loaded dynamically as well.

Comment: Oh, you're right. The title seems a little different. Still I'd bind to the `<tbody>` when the table is created.

Comment: @user2736012 -- Yeah, binding the click event upon creation is another way to go, might even be better depending on the page size.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rid').click(function() {
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yraQS/

Comment: That's the same code from the question, except that you changed the alert.

Comment: lol : if you click on 1 or 2 it works, because the 1 or 2 are the .rib class. Maybe should i color, what is the .rib class in the view ?